# Has the "accept rate" thing been removed?

Tags: discussion

What is the reason that accept rate feature has now been removed? Has it actually been removed or am I missing a point? Just curious..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Accept rate is no longer being displayed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate), as of January 2013. If you poke around [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), you can read up on the reasons why and the debates for and against displaying it, but it comes down to the fact that network-wide, accept rates did more harm than good.

Comment: much thankful to you.